# How to discover less accessed files in svn?

Tags: svn, report

I need to know the most stable classes in my repository, so I tried to use the SVNSTAT tool, It is really good but do not have the function I need.

That tool generate a report called "Files with most revisions", but I need the oposite of that "Files with less revisions" or the same but complete with all files so I will get the tail.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it

1. I developed a software to: Get all log with the following command `svn log <initial revision>:HEAD -v > svn.log`
2. Get all lines that starts with "   A " or "   M "
3. Remove "   A " and "  M " from all lines
4. Sort all lines
5. Count how many times the same path appears and Write it to a file

Then I imported the result on excel and played with...